# Spring Integration - splitter/aggregator - ending up with wrong format

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-integration, spring-amqp

I have the following XML payload, which I'm trying to use for Spring Integration and Spring Integration AMQP:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<order>
   <items>
      <item_name>Item1</item_name>
   </items>
   <items>
      <item_name>Item2</item_name>
   </items>
   <items>
      <item_name>Item3</item_name>
   </items>
</order>
```

I'm splitting the message by using a xpath-splitter:

```
<int-xml:xpath-splitter input-channel="amqpInboundChannel" output-channel="aggregateChannel">
    <int-xml:xpath-expression expression="//items"></int-xml:xpath-expression>
</int-xml:xpath-splitter>
```

I works fine and the message are being split into 3 new messages e.g. with this payload:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items>
   <item_name>Item1</item_name>
</items>
```

After this step the messages are being aggregated using this setup:

```
<int:aggregator input-channel="aggregateChannel" output-channel="channelSJ" message-store="messageStore">
</int:aggregator>

<bean id="messageStore" class="org.springframework.integration.store.SimpleMessageStore" />
```

As a final step the message is being sent to an exchange using this outbound-channel-adapter:

```
<amqp:outbound-channel-adapter channel="channelSJ" exchange-name="ex_store" routing-key="sj" amqp-template="rabbitTemplate" header-mapper="myHeaderMapper"/>

<int:channel id="channelSJ">
    <int:interceptors>
        <int:wire-tap channel="logger"/>
    </int:interceptors>      
</int:channel>
```

Unfortunately something goes wrong, because i end up with something like this payload. I need it to remain in XML format.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending a `Collection` of Strings the the AMQP adapter.

By default, that adapter can only handle `String`, `byte[]` and `Serializable`; in this case he will use Java serialization because the `Collection` is `Serializable`.

You have a couple of options...

- use a `JsonMessageConverter` in the adapter's `amqp-template` and the collection will be rendered as JSON.
- add a transformer between the aggregator and the adapter to transform the collection back to a single `String`.